# Importing data found to be true from one Google sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter, data-validation

I am trying to find a way to import data (text) from one sheet to another, via the same book. I assume it's going to need an IF or IFS formula because I only want data is that found to be "TRUE" (via the checkbox ability) to be imported into a list that has other text.

So basically, I want the data from Row A if Row B is true into a separate sheet.

Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnjmGPyzj7YsGaO1M5h97c8GoJPzQeIUHkv3JGKbrL8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: I want answers found to be true on the first sheet to be added to the list on the "mastered" sheet. So nothing gets transferred over unless the checkmark is clicked (the equivalent of true). There is an array formula to the side of the chart on the first sheet that is kind of doing what I want, but its all in one cell, separated by commas and I want each individual true finding the be in its own cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) or [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Example using FILTER

```
=FILTER('Sheet 1'!A:A,'Sheet 1'!B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER('Copy of Dolch Sight Words'!A:A, 'Copy of Dolch Sight Words'!B:B = TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

```
=FILTER({'Copy of Dolch Sight Words'!A:A,'Copy of Dolch Sight Words'!C:L}, 
'Copy of Dolch Sight Words'!B:B = TRUE)
```

[image: 0]